# angularjs mobile website: fix top bar with sliding menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, mobile-website

I´m trying to implement a mobile website using Angularjs.
I want to use this sort of structure:

- top fix bar
- with a menu sliding in from left to right (clicking on the logo)
- and possibly a drop down menu on the right hand side.

Similar to gmail:

[image]

Basically, a sort of (Android) action bar but for a mobile website.

As I don´t want to reinvent the wheel, is there any good reference or sort of seed project I can use?

Answer (score 2):

1. the top fixed bar: use bootstrap, it already has a fixed navbar as "navbar-fixed-top"...see [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top)
2. slide menu: there is an awesome angularjs plugin which does exactly this: [Angular-snap.js](https://github.com/jtrussell/angular-snap.js)

follow the steps there...you'll have to add three main files: angular-snap.js, snap.js and angular-snap.css and add the 'snap' module as a dependency in your app.js file:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['snap']);
```

done. All you'll need in your main code is a drawer and some content:

```
<snap-drawer>
  I'm in a drawer!
</snap-drawer>

<snap-content>
  I'm your main content!
</snap-content>
```

1. dropdown menu at the right: again in bootstrap...put [this](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns) in the fixed navbar